# Input Box for Text to Columns Fixed Width - Excel Crashing

Tags: arrays, vba, excel, macros

I am trying to use an input box to ask users to input the length of the account numbers that are being utilized in the data, which could vary, and then split the column based on the fixed width input by the user. In my research I have only been able to find inserting two `len` formulas in separate columns and then deleting the original. I am trying to avoid that if possible.

Here is the code that I currently have:

```
   Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue
   Message = "Input the character length of the account numbers."
   Title = "Account Number Length"
   Default = "4"
   MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)

    'Split Account numbers
    Columns("B:B").Select
    Selection.TextToColumns Destination:=Range("B1"), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        OtherChar:=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(MyValue, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True
```

When I try to use the `MyValue` as a part of the `FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(MyValue, 1))` excel crashes. Is there a way to define this or input it so that the input value will be inserted into the `Array(MyValue, 1)` as a value and not cause Excel to crash?

For instance, if the account number length is 4, then the return value should be Array(4, 1).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
Sub test()

   Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue

   Dim rngRaw As Range


   Message = "Input the character length of the account numbers."
   Title = "Account Number Length"

   Default = "4"
  '/ Pass as numeric
   MyValue = Val(InputBox(Message, Title, Default))

    'Split Account numbers
    'Columns("B:B").Select

    'Instead of full column try with data range. Avoids crash.
    Set rngRaw = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(2) '/ Change as per your actual data.

    rngRaw.TextToColumns Destination:=rngRaw.cells(1,1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        OtherChar:=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(MyValue, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

'/ Update as per user's query in comment
'// Another version with do-loop. I don't recommend this though

```
Sub test()

   Dim Message, Title, Default, MyValue As String
   Dim rngRaw As Range

   Dim lDelLen      As Long

   Message = "Input the character length of the account numbers."
   Title = "Account Number Length"

   Default = "4"
  '/ Pass as numeric
    MyValue = "Foo"

    Do
        MyValue = InputBox(Message, Title, Default)
        'If a user presses cancel then MyValue
        '  is a vbNullString and we should allow the
        '  user to abort the entire sub
        If MyValue = vbNullString Then Exit Sub
        If IsNumeric(MyValue) Then Exit Do
    Loop

    lDelLen = Val(MyValue)

    'Split Account numbers
    'Columns("B:B").Select

    'Instead of full column try with data range. Avoids crash.
    Set rngRaw = Sheet1.UsedRange.Columns(2) '/ Change as per your actual data.

    rngRaw.TextToColumns Destination:=rngRaw.Cells(1, 1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, _
        OtherChar:=":", FieldInfo:=Array(Array(0, 1), Array(lDelLen, 1)), _
        TrailingMinusNumbers:=True

End Sub
```

Comment: Just as an additional refinement you might want to consider declaring `MyValue` as a string and the check `If IsNumeric(MyValue) Then`. Just in case and for good measures.

Comment: @Ralph I got the msgbox to pop up, but it ends the sub if it errors out. The macro inserts sheets, and columns, etc. which just running again would cause error. Is there a way to loop the msgbox error back to the input screen if it occurs?

Comment: I allowed myself to make a slight update to the answer and improve the `Do...Loop`: now the user can press cancel and the sub gets aborted. Otherwise, the InputBox shows in an endless loop and this (I agree with @cyboashu) is not recommendable. I sure hope cyboashu doesn't mind my update minor update.